# Change data-image attribut via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, image, transition

I automatically change the image of a div with the data-image attribute via jQuery. Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var img_array = [1, 2],
            newIndex = 0,
            index = 0,
            interval = 5000;

        (function changeBg() {
            index = (index + 1) % img_array.length;

            $('#backgroundimg').attr('data-image', function () {
                $('#backgroundimg').animate({
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
                }, 1000, function () {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('#backgroundimg').animate({
                            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,255,255)'
                        }, 1000);
                    }, 3000);
                });
                return 'http://www.eric-schwab.de/images/other/background/'+img_array[index]+'.jpg';
            });
            setTimeout(changeBg, interval);
        })();
});
```

and here is my div:

```
<div id="backgroundimg" ></div>
```

When I inspect the element, I am able to see that the data-image changes, but I can't see the image.
What am I doing wrong here?

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/eLbkvabx/2/

EDIT: I am using the [imageScroll.js](https://www.google.no/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fpederan%2FParallax-ImageScroll&ei=oxpOVZCXJcKcsgHHyIA4&usg=AFQjCNGf2T9zQwfRhGHUtmX_wwasWHWmXA&bvm=bv.92885102,d.bGg) plugin and this is my [website](http://www.eric-schwab.de/test) where I would like to apply it.

I appreciate any help and hints!

Kindly

Eric

Comment: you will have to somehow make the plugin you are using to realize that that the attribute ha been changed

Comment: hmm, any idea how I could do this?

Comment: havent worked on the plugin

Comment: What parallax effect are you talking about? Is this jquery plugin? How do you include and itinialize this?

Answer (score 0):

By setting your `div` with the `data-image` attribute you won't see any image apply in your div.

In order to apply a background-image to your `div` use the `css` function of jQuery:

```
$('#backgroundimg').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately, I am bound to the data-image attribute, because I am using a parallax effect with jQuery which requires this type of inserting images.

Comment: Thank you too Vladimir! But the image is not changing... Beside that, I am forced to use the data-image attribute because my parallax plugin.